# Can't output array in javascript alert

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a textarea for users to enter numbers separated by a new line.
I am using this code to assign all of the numbers into an array

```
 var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value.split('\n');
```

However when I try to do an alert

```
alert("First element: " + arrayOfLines[0]);
```

My output ignores the array and only looks like:

> First element:

So I need to know how to output the first element of the array through alert.

Comment: To output an array use `console.log(arrayOfLines[0])` not the `alert()`

Comment: try to `console.log` it instead, if the value is `undefined` or such, it will tell it. In an alert, you can also try with `JSON.stringify(value)`

Comment: Are you sure that your input has a value? The only reason I could think for this to happen is if either your input with that ID does not exist or the input doesn't have a value. Also, if any other elements with that same id exist then only the first one is found.

Comment: See here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FK1W5FVK69S4